# eth_getBlockByNumber returning undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, rpc

I have some JavaScript that's connecting to a private ethereum network via JSON-RPC. I am trying to extract the transaction hash of the blocks but am unable to do so.

```
// BlockNumber
clientNodeOne.call({"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":1},
        function(err, res) {
          if (err) console.log(err)
          console.log("MINER ONE block number: " + parseInt(res.result, 16) )
          miner_one_block_number = parseInt(res.result, 16);
        })

        // console.log("BLOCK NUMBER: " + miner_one_block_number);

// Block Hash
clientNodeOne.call({"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":[miner_one_block_number, false],"id":1},
      function(err, res) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        console.log("MINER ONE transaction hash: " + res.result)
      })
```

The first call to read the block number works great. I am saving the block number to another variable, miner_one_block_number. I am then passing that variable into the input parameters for the call to eth_getBlockByNumber. Instead of getting the transaction hash for that block, I am instead getting a value of undefined. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is failing because the block number passed as the first parameter to `eth_gasBlockByNumber` must be a hex string. Instead of doing `parseInt(res.result, 16)`, just store res.result directly and pass that in.

Comment: Hey I removed the parse int and stored the res.result directly. But instead of undefined, I get an [object Object]. Any ideas? Thank you for your help btw.

Comment: Nevermind got it! Used stringify to get the result.